# MySQL join query - how to approach 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm new to SQL and starting to look at joins.

Say i have three tables like so: 1. temperature, 2. drink, 3. drink_temp

```
temp_id    | temp
----------------------
1          |  cold
2          |  hot
3          |  warm


drink_id | drink 
---------------------
12       |  tea 
16       |  coke 
20       |  coffee 


drink_id | temp_id
------------------------
12       |  3
16       |  1
20       |  2
```

What sort of query would be required to produce an output where I can match the temperatures to the drinks, by only getting the ids to match? i.e:

```
drink   |  temp 
------------------
tea     |  warm 
coke    |  cold 
coffee  |  hot
```

I know I need some form of join. I've tried a left join between temperature and drink, but it's not working for me. I have looked at a fair few questions related to this and the only thing that is confusing me is having 3 tables to match up.

Thanks!

Comment: SELECT drink,temp FROM drink JOIN drink_temp ON drink.drink_id=drink_temp.drink_id JOIN temperature ON temperature.temp_id=drink_temp.variety_id

Comment: Is there a special reason why you put the answer in a comment?

Comment: @Lennart Perhaps because it's a bit trivial?

Comment: Since the question was trivial I see nothing wrong with a trivial answer. I can imagine it to be a question that some beginners are facing, and it will be easier to find the answer if it is an answer.

Comment: @Strawberry apologies for the 'trivial' question, but i think it's valid nonetheless for a beginner.

Comment: @Cheung I don't. There's no primer on SQL that wouldn't cover this, and it adds nothing to the cannon of knowledge that is SO.

Comment: @Strawberry why not point me in that direction then instead of adding a 'trivial' comment to the already, according to you, 'trivial' question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a left join or any sort of outer join makes sense here.  This should be a straight forward inner join.

I don't know your data model too well.  Given the 3 tables you supplied, I am going to *assume* that variety_id is a temperature_id.

```
select d.drink, t.temp
from drink d
inner join drink_temp dt ON dt.drink_id = d.drink_id 
inner join temperature t ON t.temp_id = dt.variety_id
where d.drink_id in (:firstDrinkId, :secondDrinkId);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! You are correct, I had the id mixed up with a different table. It is indeed temp_id.

Answer (score 0):

Three table JOIN syntax in SQL:

```
SELECT t1.col, t3.col FROM table1
join table2 ON table1.primarykey = table2.foreignkey 
join table3 ON table2.primarykey = table3.foreignkey
```